# Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [43]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21

Tags: ssis, bids, ssis-2012

My source is a TXT Flat File Source, the Destination is of type OLE DB. (see image)

[image]

I found a very [basic tutorial on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-1-Basics) to create a package. I finished the steps but when debugging I get a strange error(bellow):

Can someone give an explanation to this error? It took me hours to search the web for the error.

> SSIS package
> "C:\Users\USRNAME\Desktop\Projects\DataGeneratorSsis\DataGeneratorSsis\Package.dtsx"
> starting. Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline:
> Validation phase is beginning. Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow
> Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning. Warning:
> 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column
> "intApplication" (7) on output "Flat File Source Output" (6) and
> component "Flat File Source" (2) is not subsequently used in the Data
> Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow
> task performance. Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task,
> SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning. Information:
> 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is
> beginning. Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source
> [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-1-Basics): The processing of file "C:\Users\USRNAME\Desktop\ddd.txt" has
> started. Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline:
> Execute phase is beginning. Information: 0x402090DE at Data Flow Task,
> Flat File Source [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-1-Basics): The total number of data rows processed for file
> "C:\Users\USRNAME\Desktop\ddd.txt" is 2. Error: 0xC0202009 at Data
> Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [43]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
> An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21. An OLE DB record
> is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80040E21 Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation
> generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No
> work was done.". Error: 0xC020901C at Data Flow Task, OLE DB
> Destination [43]: There was an error with OLE DB
> Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[AppID] on OLE DB
> Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status
> returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential
> loss of data.". Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB
> Destination [43]: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "OLE DB
> Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error
> code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB
> Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on
> error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
> component. There may be error messages posted before this with more
> information about the failure. Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task,
> SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The
> ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (43) failed with
> error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination
> Input" (56). The identified component returned an error from the
> ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
> error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> about the failure. Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task,
> SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning. Information:
> 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-1-Basics): The processing of
> file "C:\Users\USRNAME\Desktop\ddd.txt" has ended. Information:
> 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination"
> wrote 0 rows. Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task,
> SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning. Task failed: Data Flow Task
> Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code
> DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but
> the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1);
> resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches
> the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
> MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. SSIS package
> "C:\Users\USRNAME\Desktop\Projects\DataGeneratorSsis\DataGeneratorSsis\Package.dtsx"
> finished: Failure.

The relevant error message

> There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[AppID] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So this error is occurring because you have a value in your source for the AppID column that is not valid for your AppID column in the destination.

Some possible examples:

- You're trying to insert a 10 character value into an 8 character field.
- You're trying to insert a value larger than 127 into a tinyint field.
- You're trying to insert the value 6.4578 into a decimal(5,1) field.

SSIS is governed by metadata, and it expects that you've set up your inputs and outputs properly such that the acceptable values for both are within the same range.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by truncation (the incoming value is too large to fit in the destination column). Unfortunately SSIS will not tell you the name of the offending column. I use a third-party component to get this information: http://naseermuhammed.wordpress.com/tips-tricks/getting-error-column-name-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to receive this error from a select component if the query fails in an unusual manner (eg: a sub-query returns multiple rows in an oracle oledb connection)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Adding OP's solution from a [rejected edit to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3041969):</sub>

> THE PROBLEM:
>
> - AppID was stored in the Source as an integer, but in the Destination all fields expect a 100-character [string].
>
> THE SOLUTION:
>
> - Try putting a 'Data Conversion' component between the Source and Destination (as illustrated in image).
> - Double Click the 'Data Conversion' component to open the 'Data Conversion Transformation Editor', set the correct Data Types to 'string [DT_STR]' and the length to '100'.
>
> [image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case the underlying system account through which the package was running was locked out. Once we got the system account unlocked and reran the package, it executed successfully. The developer said that he got to know of this while debugging wherein he directly tried to connect to the server and check the status of the connection.

Comment: This would be a problem for any error message; it's wholly outside the scope of the error shown here.

Answer (score -1):

Error jet 4 oledb It Can be possible upgrade kb4041678 kb4041681

Comment: Can you add some more details, issue will be fixed by upgrading to any specific version?