# Can't import excel file to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to upload my excel file to my sql but getting those message -

1. Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB
   record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
   Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".  (SQL
   Server Import and Export Wizard)
2. Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task There was an error with Destination - TRANSAC.Inputs[Destination
   Input].Columns[F6] on Destination - TRANSAC.Inputs[Destination
   Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the
   integrity constraints for the column.".  (SQL Server Import and
   Export Wizard)
3. Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination -
   TRANSAC.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code
   0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination -
   TRANSAC.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An
   error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
   about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
   Error
   0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
   "Destination - TRANSAC" (32) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
   processing input "Destination Input" (45). The identified component
   returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific
   to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow
   task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this
   with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and
   Export Wizard)

Comment: Have you tried searching for the error codes? E.g. [Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination \[43\]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093339/error-0xc0202009-at-data-flow-task-ole-db-destination-43-ssis-error-code-dt) could give you a good start on solving it.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us; we can read your inside voice just fine. Thanks.

Comment: See also this answer on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/172175).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Excel file to a CSV file and bulk import the data.  Also, you can save the data as a text file and do the same.  Or, use VBA in Excel to push the data to SQL Server.  There are other ways to get data from various sources to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found was a long way but works  perfectly. In my case I have car-return inside of the text on one of the column and this was screwing my copy-paste when tried to "edit the first 200 rows" on SQL server. This is what I did:

- Create a new Access database
- Import the excel file there
- Save As .mdb
- Import from SQL Server Management Studio using Import Wizard. Which is in:
  Right Click on your database > Tasks > Import Data > Data Source = Access